# Time required to achieve change in velocity when acceleration varies with velocity.

Tags: physics

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54586/converting-a-function-for-velocity-vs-position-vx-to-position-vs-time) is similar, but I am a bit out of practice on mathematics and struggle to apply the steps to my problem.
**How can the $\triangle$$t$ be calculated for a given $\triangle$$v$ when acceleration changes as a function of $v$?**

Given:

$a(v) =- \frac{8.69+0.0252v^{2}}{200}$

My current goal is to find the time required to change from $v=70$ to $v=60$. (velocity: $\frac{km}{hr}$, acceleration: $\frac{km}{hr/s}$)

---

My approach:

I have tried to use the linked question to rewrite $a(v)$ as $v(t)$.  Then I would set the equation equal to 70 and then 60 respectively and solve for $\triangle$$t$.

I do not understand where $U$ comes from in the linked problem.

---

Semi-related question, are the steps above necessary for expressing $a(v)$ in terms $a(t)$?

Comment: If the acceleration is always positive, why would the velocity ever decrease?

Comment: $U$ “comes from” the equation that starts with “$U(q)=$“. That’s the definition of $U$. But note that the linked question is asking about distance, not time. Time is easier than distance and there is not so much need to define a function such as $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=a+b v^2\implies \frac{dv}{a+bv^2}=dt\implies 
\Delta t=\frac1{\sqrt{ab}}\left[\arctan\sqrt{\frac ab}v\right]_{v_1}^{v_2}.
$$

Comment: I have integrated as you have listed and all of those values are off by a factor of 3.6, which is the conversion factor between km/hr and m/s.  I assume the math is right because of the predictability of the results but I do not know where the 3.6 conversion factor came from or went.  I will convert a(v) to be a function of m/s instead of km/hr to see if your equation aligns.

Comment: When the conversion factor of 3.6 is applied the equation works perfectly.  Now I need to figure out how to use this information for my larger problem.  Thank you.